# opencart change htaccess for seo urls

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I am totally new to opencart and my client needs to make frienldy urls on his blog pages for example: http://mastermontag.ru/index.php?route=pavblog/category&id=26

So I need to rewrite my `.htaaccess` file

This my file right now:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

# redirect www to one www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
# END redirect www to one www

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
1.to
1.To
Igor
Igor 1:23 am
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to make urls seo friendly**

1. Rename htaccess.txt file in your opencart directory to .htaccess
2. In your admin panel under setting find server tab.
3. Find SEO url and enable it.

Then you are done.
To make your .htaccess file work you needs to enable SEO url.

For all urls like `index.php?route=common/home` you just need to add following line to your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?route=$1/$2 [L]
```

then your SEO Friendly URL becomes www.example.com/common/home

Now you are done.

Comment: I did it. Now it works on main pages. But does not working on blog pages. Blog is additional modulebtw.

Comment: You might have to add additional rules in your .htaccess file.